# EC2 status unhealthy in Target Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am using AWS application load balancer to connect to a target group that has an EC2 instance with docker installed using cloud init scripts. I am executing an Nginx dockercontainer inside EC2.

I am getting a request time out exception as an information.

I connected to the target and checked if the service is available. I received nginx default page. Performing a curl -I on the internal IP also gives a response code as 200.

Please help me in understanding how I can troubleshoot this to get the root cause.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your EC2 instance security group allowing connections on the health check port ?

Comment: Yes. It is. However should it be to specific IP or anywhere?

Comment: pls add in details of what url is the health check configured to hit and your security group details.

Comment: if it is not fully open (0.0.0.0/0) then add the security group attached to the ALB in an ingress rule in the EC2 instance security group

Comment: Thanks guys. After giving access to anywhere on instance NSG, the issue is resolved. However, it is a bit scary as anyone anywhere can access the port. Isn’t it security issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The configuration should be:

- A security group on the Application Load Balancer (`ALB-SG`) permitting inbound traffic from, presumably, the whole Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`) on the appropriate ports (80, 443?)
- A security group on the EC2 instance (`App-SG`) that permits inbound access from `ALB-SG` on the appropriate ports (80, 443?)

That is, `App-SG` should specifically reference `ALB-SG`. (Type in the name, it will resolve to a `sg-xxx` ID.)